# How can I remove unwanted CSS based on react routing in a website?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, react-router

How do I remove unused css in a webpage?

I could see that bundled css takes more time to load when I try in performance. I was trying to optimize that case by rendering the bundled css based on page wise (using react routing)

Example: There is a webpage called 'A'. If I load the page, the css used in that page alone should render. other css should not loaded or used. like wise it has to be done for every other pages.

Comment: You just need to link the necessary css to each of your conainers

Comment: What Niels said and then use code splitting, check out the react [Code Splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) guide.